# Pop up box in a chart c# Form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, charts

Right so I have a Form with a chart displaying data in series as bars, want I want to be able to do is to mouse over a bar and get more in depth detail. I am working out the best way to be able to mouse over a specific bar as right now I just have an event for hovering over the entire chart. not sure how to do that, I also am looking for some kind of little pop up box to appear when i mouse over, not a message box, a small box of text to appear in front of the chart to display the data, I think I will need my own custom form for that. So any help with either working out how to mouse over a specific bar with an event or how to help with a small display box?

Comment: This kind of popup is called a tooltip. It would be helpful to know exactly which kind of chart control you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around Steps before writing the custom Chart

1. Drag and drop a "ToolTip" control in your form.
2. On "MouseHover" event of your Chart Control Use the following line of code to display the data dynamically on the ToolTip.

   `toolTip1.SetToolTip(chart1 //Bascially the id Value of the Control, "Hello" // String Value be displayed on the ToolTip );`

Some other Visual Properties of the ToolTip to make it look good

```
toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Details";
toolTip1.UseFading = true;
toolTip1.UseAnimation = true;
toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
```

Comment: If you give the toolTip as a common control it will appear every where in the form , so its better to give an event for the control and specify that in it so that the toolTip appears only on the control

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the ToolTip property of the Chart.Series[i] object. No other objects or event handlers are needed.